# Can a "Custom View" be stored to a custom default template and thus be made available to all Excel workbooks, new and old?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Repetitive daily task:

1. Pull Excel sheet ("workbook") from database.
2. Adjust column widths.
3. Apply certain filters to certain columns.
4. Apply some conditional formatting here and there.

   - Objective: I'd like to **automate** steps 2.-4. as much as possible.

What comes to mind are [custom views](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-apply-or-delete-a-custom-view-HP010342377.aspx). The current catch is that there is no button equivalent to *"make this custom view available for **all** worksheets / workbooks"*. And by **all** I mean also existing (non-blank / non-"new") Excel files, such as the one pulled in the first step.

I am not sure if [templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP010197489.aspx#BM3) would do the trick for this, that is, **the combination of custom views with a custom default template** containing the previously defined custom view.

Before I go and create a mess of my Excel installation: Is this feasible and/or is there a simpler/better way to accomplish the goal?

<sub>VBA macros would be o.k. too but I hope are *not* necessary for this little exercise...</sub>

Comment: duplicate of sorts: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-custom-view-for-use-in/7ef25ab0-2ba8-4044-993c-ce1417cfa600 but this doesn't yet provide a satisfactory answer :(

Answer (score 1):

I think VBA is the way to go on this. You could consider going into the XML - I thought that custom views might be defined as a separate XML file in the XLSX archive. But it's just a `<customWorkbookViews>` section in the `xl\workbook.xml` file. And you could maybe do it with a template, depending on how your application works. But honestly, the simplest thing is probably just to record a VBA macro in the Personal Macro Workbook (so it's always available) and add it to the Quick Access Toolbar. (Yes, I try to avoid VBA where possible, but here it's the best way.)

Comment: Done some VBA coding a looong while back. Does recording a macro in Excel essentially just record every click or keyboard input and translate that into executable code, no coding skills required? Does it work pretty well, robustly and efficiently?

Comment: @ "depending on how your application works": fairly simple: the data is pulled into an Excel file which is stored in the standard temporary file folder. Close to a hundred columns with thousands of rows. Plain vanilla.