# In Excel, will a custom default template be applied to **all** files (or only to new, blank ones)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

... where by **all** Excel files I mean to include, for example, those received via email from other people (who might be using a different Excel template) or an Excel file pulled off a database.

- Will a (custom) default template be "always on", no matter the origin of the Excel file?

<sub>Related question: [Can a "Custom View" be stored to a custom default template and thus be made available to all Excel workbooks, new and old?](https://superuser.com/questions/831019/is-it-possible-to-make-a-personal-custom-view-available-via-a-custom-default-t)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Templates are used to create new files. They do not effect existing files automatically. Nor do they effect every file you open with Excel because each file retains it's own settings.

You can create and save a custom [personal templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/save-a-workbook-as-a-template-HA102809716.aspx) for your own use.  These will then show up as selectable templates on the `File`>`New` section. Alternately, you can safe the file to any folder and create a new file by opening it directly.

[image]

If you want to modify the template used when creating a new blank workbook, then you need to open a blank workbook, modify it to your liking and save it as a template file (xltx) in `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\XLSTART`

Note: This will change how EVERY new blank workbook appears. So, use it carefully.