# Setting Excel 2013 default theme

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, themes

I want to change the default theme for Excel, so that when I open a new blank document, the right fonts and colors are in place. I've come so far as to make a theme and set it as default, but for some reason new documents use the Office theme instead of the Default theme. This is what all new documents are like:

[image: This is what it looks like.]

I've been scouring the internet for a solution to this problem and nothing I find seems to work. Tried [this](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Change-the-default-theme-3b0d77d4-9d33-4bd2-91f9-d95ce39c66b3) and [that](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904), but it doesn't work.

So far I've:

- Created a blank workbook;
- Applied the theme;
- Saved it as a template (book.xltx) in the default template directory.
- Tried different casing (Book.xltx) for the file name.
- Tried changing the default template directory and placing the files there.
- Looked into other 'default' template directories for different users, public users, all users, etc.

Still, no luck. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Excel is making you pick a "type" of file to work with when you open it in 2013, right? I imagine the issue is there. You are picking "blank workbook" right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Excel, will a custom default template be applied to \*\*all\*\* files (or only to new, blank ones)?](http://superuser.com/questions/831067/in-excel-will-a-custom-default-template-be-applied-to-all-files-or-only-to)

Comment: @Raystafarian This question is entirely different from the one you're pointing out as a possible duplicate. Mine is not working on new documents, his is not working on existing documents. Also Excel doesn't ask me what kind of document I want to make. It just starts on a blank one.

Answer (score 4):

The `Book.xltx` file must be placed here in order to use your new default theme in Excel.

  ```
  C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
  ```

All other MS Office templates (Word, PowerPoint, Outlook), are placed here:

  ```
  C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by K-Lynn is correct except for this one detail, since going through the default UI creates a workbook from the Office default.

Go to File > Options, then:

Under start up options, disable "Show the Start screen when this application starts" to use the template you placed in the ~/XLSTART directory.

Additionally, saving the same Book.xltx template as Sheet.xltx will allow new sheets to be generated with the same template.

Reference : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/excel-2013-change-default-template/6c6387d0-211c-4f6e-a856-3501324d5098

Comment: What does Sheet.xltx required for exactly? I am only using a few new Cell Styles along with modified comma and currency styles. All my new sheets have the same styles enabled as the main sheet (Sheet1) when Book.xltx is in place.